# Backbone.xmpp and strophe.vcard.js for Backbone plugin: getting vCard asynchroniously

Tags: backbone.js, xmpp

I used Backbone.xmpp and strophe.roster.js for Backbone successfully with

```
var p = $.Deferred();                      
p = conn.roster.get();   
p.done(function(roster) {
   ...
});
```

Now I want to get the vCard with the [strophe.vcard.js](http://ggozad.com/strophe.plugins/docs/strophe.vcard.html) for Backbone plugin. The same approach doesn't work. I tried v0.1 and v0.2...

```
var p = $.Deferred();                      
p = conn.vCard.get(someJid);   
p.done(function(vCard) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Did you try `conn.vcard.get`? JavaScript is case sensitive and I think this is written in lower case

Comment: yeah, I tried it, although in the plugin it is registered under "vCard", so actually it must be it. But I think it has to do with the asynchronious call which has to be done somehow differently.

Comment: According to [this example](https://github.com/thepug/strophejs-plugins/blob/master/vcard/examples/strophevcard.js#L36) you have to put your callback into the `get` method

Comment: nope, it didn't work. It's not the original plugin from the strophe.js site. I added the link to the plugin above.